# Google Realtime and JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx

So, I am attempting to use the Google Realtime Javascript API through a WebView in a vanilla JavaFX application.. without really knowing what I am doing mainly because my knowledge of web development and JavaScript is quite weak.

I've started simply by bundling the index.html and the realtime-client-utils.js with my JavaFX app and attempting to get the quickstart example working in a WebView.

I am already using the Java Google Drive API in my app, so I have a valid client ID.

I simply got stuck in authentication... the application does not authenticate and clicking the "You must authorize"-button does nothing at all. It should open a login popup, as far as I understood.

Here's a snippet of code from the realtime-client-utils.js, this code ought to be called when the button is clicked, but like I said, nothing happens.

```
var authorizeWithPopup = function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: [
        rtclient.INSTALL_SCOPE,
        rtclient.FILE_SCOPE,
        rtclient.OPENID_SCOPE
      ],
      user_id: userId,
      immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);
    console.log(clientId);
  };
```

What might be wrong?

Has anyone here successfully used the Realtime API with JavaFX WebView?

Does anyone know if Google has plans to create a Java API for it's realtime engine?

Comment: Have you created a [PopupHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#createPopupHandlerProperty) for your [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/package-summary.html)?

Comment: If you want to know Google's API plans, it is probably best to ask them directly yourself.